# Unable to control 24 VDC brushed motor with dev boards

Tags: dc-motor, driver, h-bridge

I'm designing a board that has to control several DC brushed motors. The motors are SY54E-DC24V-2PCE. I didn't find a datasheet but some references like [this](https://twistedquarter.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=3512) and [this](https://maxxgrab.com/products/sy54e-dc-24v-taiwanese-gantry-motor-part-no-rj54-b3-dc24v).

I measured the DC resistance of the windings and it is 3.9 ohm.
Powering up the motor with 24VDC, without any load, it draws about 350 mA.

I bought some dev boards to test the drivers before selecting them for my custom board.
On my desk I have:

- [DRV8256PEVM](https://www.ti.com/tool/DRV8256PEVM)
- [DRV8871 breakout board](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3190)
- [L293D Arduino shield](https://electropeak.com/l293d-motor-drive-shield)

[DRV8256](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8256.pdf) is rated for 2.5A and after playing with all the settings the motor barely spins but with a very rough and irregular motion.

[DRV8871](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8871.pdf) is rated for 3.6A (I disabled the current control) but the motor never spins.

[L293D](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/l293.pdf) is rated for 1.2A only (even the datasheet describe it as "high-current" driver) but it is the only one driver that can run the motor, though with a very loud noise (right now I'm using a 500 Hz PWM).

I really cannot use a large PDIP ICs on my board so I want to understand *why* the other drivers are not able to control the motor. And anyway the L293(D) has a current too low to drive the motor under load.

I understand you don't have the crystal ball, but do you have any idea about these behaviors? And if I should go deeper and try to get the other drivers to work, or it would be better to select another kind of driver...

### UPDATE

Here the current profile at power up, with the following settings:

- calibrated power supply 24.0 V (capable of more than 6A)
- shunt resistor of 10.1 ohm (measured)
- motor connected using 20 cm thick wires

[image]

As you can see from the cursors, the steady-state current is about
218 mA, while the initial peak is about 1.44 A well below the current rating of the tested drivers.

Comment: *I understand you don't have the crystal ball* - you understand correctly. A minimum you could do is to post your schematics.

Comment: Sorry, which schematics? I said I'm using the dev boards I linked.

Comment: Ok, I see. Sorry, jumped right to the drivers datasheets

Comment: Still, you should show how you configure and power the boards. Better focus on one

Comment: For DRV8871 I said it: I disabled the current control. No other settings. L293D shield has no settings. DRV8256PEVM I tried *all* (literally) the combinations the GUI allows. I also described the operating conditions: power supply voltage, PWM frequency, motor. If you need a specific detail, please ask and I will answer.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat, I apologize but I don't understand: the DRV8871 breakout board has just two screw terminals for the motor. There is no way to change the wirings: one wire to one terminal, the other wire to the other terminal.

Comment: I'm not sure about the *software* problem. There is no software involved here.

Comment: @Mark - Hi, I'm not an expert in motor drivers. However this seems to be a "based on what we believe, at least one of those drivers should work" situation. Since they *don't* work properly, then something we *think* we know likely isn't true. I'm concerned about the lack of data on the motor. I wonder perhaps its current during spin-up is higher than expected, and higher than the drivers can cope with? To confirm/deny this hypothesis, I would be collecting current profile data during motor spin-up (e.g. shunt resistor & scope) & checking voltage drop on interconnecting wires. Can you do that?

Comment: @SamGibson, done. Please check if it can be useful to understand what happens.

Comment: Please, instead of downvoting or ask for close the question, ask for details you need, like other users did.

Comment: @Mark - Thanks for that added info. I agree, there's no indication of a peak that exceeds what (e.g.) the DRV8871 should cope with (I just picked one driver to read about, in the limited time available). My next step would be to investigate the supply to the motor, using whichever driver you can best understand. For example, do you see an initial current peak and then the driver cuts-off the current? How big/long is that peak? Or is there a constant lower current all the time, with no peak? Things like that. Compare those results when driving a smaller motor. What do the differences tell you?